# React Date Picker On Change DATE Props type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am working with the date range using react date picker with typescript. Can anyone help me with the props type of dates that comes in handle on change. Check the attached image below. Here in onChange function **dates** is coming as an argument I want to figure out that's type in typescript.
[Code Image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yugdW.png)

Comment: did you try `typeof dates`?

Comment: Date type?  Yes it's not working cause the argument dates here is an array which has two object start and end